# How should I normalize a vector in Matlab where the sum is 1?

Tags: matlab, normalize, norm

I need to normalize a vector of N integers so that:

- Each value is proportional to its original value (the value will be between 0 and 1)
- The sum of all values is =1

For instance:

If I have a vector

```
V = [2,2,1,0]
```

the normalized vector should should be:

```
V_norm = [0.4,0.4,0.2,0]  % 0.4+0.4+0.2 = 1
```

I tried with many solutions found in this community and on the web and finally I did it with this code:

```
part = norm(V);
if part > 0
  V_norm = V/part;
else % part = 0 --> avoid "divide by 0" 
  V_norm = part;
end
```

The problem this works if:

- all elements of array are "0" --> resultant array doesn't change
- only one element of the array is >0 and all other elements are = 0 --> resultant array: the element >0 is 1 and the other 0

but if I have a different case,although the result is proportional,the sum is not 0.
For instance:

```
   V = [1,0,1]
   V_norm = [0.74,0,0.74]

   V = [1,1,1]
   V_norm = [0.54,0.54,0.54]
```

(I'm not sure if the number are correct because I can't use Matlab right now but I'm sure the sum is > 1 )

Ahy hint?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **... the normalized vector should should be:**
>
> `v_norm = [0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0];  % 0.4+0.4+0.2 = 1`

That depends. What is your [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) function?

`norm(x)` in MATLAB returns the standard norm, meaning the sum **of the squares** of the elements of a normalized vector `x` is 1.

In your example:

```
v = [1, 1, 1];         %# norm(v) = sqrt(1^2+1^2+1^2) = ~1.7321
v_norm = v / norm(v);  %# v_norm = [0.5574, 0.5574, 0.5574]
```

`sum(v_norm .^ 2)` indeed yields 1, but `sum(v_norm)` does not, as expected.

> **I need to normalize a vector of N integers so that each value is proportional to its original value (the value will be between 0 and 1) and the sum of all values is 1.**

What do you mean by "*normalize*"? Does that mean dividing by a value which is a valid mathematical norm function, according to the [norm definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition)?

What do you mean by "*proportional*"? Does that imply that all elements are multiplied by that *same* number? If it does, and it's a valid mathematical norm, you cannot guarantee that the sum of the elements will always be 1.
For instance, consider `v = [1, -2]`. Then `sum(v) = -1`.

Or maybe `sum` is the function you're looking for, but it doesn't mathematically qualify as a norm, because *a norm is a function that assigns a strictly positive length or size to all vectors in a vector space*.
In the example above, `sum(v)` is negative.

> **Ahy hint?**

You can choose either:

1. `sum(x)`, which fulfills both requirements but doesn't qualify as a norm function since it can yield negative values.
2. `norm(x, 1)`, as OleThomsenBuus suggested, which actually calculates `sum(abs(x(:)))`.
   It won't fulfill both your requirements unless you restrict your vector space to non-negative vectors.

Answer (score 10):

What you need to do is, I believe, normalize using the [1-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm) (taxicab norm):

```
v = [2, 2, 1, 0];
v_normed = v / norm(v, 1); % using the 1-norm
```

Variable `v_normed` should now be `[0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0]`. The 1-norm of `v_normed` will equal 1. You can also sum the vector (similar to the 1-norm, but without applying the absolute function to each value), but the range of that sum will be between -1 to 1 in the general case (if any values in `v` are below 0). You could use `abs` on the resulting sum, but mathematically it will no longer qualify as a norm.

Comment: Like I stated in my answer, it still doesn't fulfill the OP's two requirements for _all_ vectors, but at least it mathematically qualifies as a norm.

Answer (score 6):

If there are no furhter conditions to your normalization than you gave at the beginning of your question, a possible solution would be

```
V = [3 4 -2];
S = sum(V);
if (S == 0)
    % no solution
else
    V_norm = V ./ S;
end
sum(V_norm)
```

Comment: As a sidenote, `sum(v)` cannot mathematically qualify as a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) because it can yield negative values.

Comment: Doesn't fulfill the requirement of all values being between 0 and 1 (considering negative elements).

Comment: I agree. I shouldn't have been using the "normalization" instead of "norm", as did the OP. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: there is no need for dot in `./`

Comment: @Serg That's correct. Still I consider it good practice to use `.` whenever applying scalar operators to a vector, because it makes the code unambigous.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave here my solution for "normalizing" the rows of a matrix with positive entries, where normalization means that the row-sums are 1 after the procedure.

#### Summary

```matlab
normmat = normr(sqrt(mat)).^2
```

#### Minimal Example

`mat` is your matrix with positive entries

```matlab
mat = [1 2 3; 2 3 4]
```

```
mat =

     1     2     3
     2     3     4
```

Now we do the one-liner:

```matlab
normmat = normr(sqrt(mat)).^2
```

```
normmat =

    0.1667    0.3333    0.5000
    0.2222    0.3333    0.4444
```

The sum of each row is 1.

```matlab
sum(normmat, 2)
```

```
ans =

    1.0000
    1.0000
```

Proportions within one row are constant

```matlab
normmat ./ mat
```

```
ans =

    0.1667    0.1667    0.1667
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
```

Not necessarily the most efficient but it's one line.